# Convert old (EE2) addon to EE6

Tags: add-on-development

wondering if anyone can help me convert this to EE6. Thanks

```
<?php

/**
* @package ExpressionEngine
* @author Wouter Vervloet
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2010, Baseworks
* @license    http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
* 
* This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported.
* To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
* or send a letter to Creative Commons, 171 Second Street, Suite 300,
* San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.
* 
*/

if ( ! defined('EXT')) { exit('Invalid file request'); }

class Royal_titles
{
  public $settings            = array();
  
  public $name                = 'Royal Titles';
  public $version             = 0.6;
  public $description         = "Enable EE global variables for the default weblog title setting.";
  public $settings_exist      = 'n';
  public $docs_url            = '';
  
    // -------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // -------------------------------
    function Royal_titles($settings='')
    {
      $this->__construct($settings);
    }
    
    function __construct($settings='')
    {     
        $this->settings = $settings;    
    }
    // END Super_titles
    
    function parse_preferences($data = array())
    {
      
      global $LOC, $PREFS;
      
      $val = $data['default_entry_title'];
      
      if( ! $val ) return $data;
              
      foreach($data as $key => $var)
        {
            $val = str_replace(LD.$key.RD, $var, $val); 
        }

        if (strpos($val, LD.'current_time') !== FALSE && preg_match_all("/".LD."current_time\s+format=([\"\'])([^\\1]*?)\\1".RD."/", $val, $matches))
        {   
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($matches['0']); $j++)
        {               
            $val = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches['0'][$j], '/')."/", $LOC->decode_date($matches['2'][$j], $LOC->now), $val, 1);              
        }
      }

      
      $data['default_entry_title'] = $val;

      return $data;
    }

    // --------------------------------
    //  Activate Extension
    // --------------------------------
    function activate_extension()
    {
      
      global $DB;

    $sql = array();

    // hooks array
    $hooks = array(
      'publish_form_weblog_preferences' => 'parse_preferences'
    );

    // insert hooks and methods
    foreach ($hooks AS $hook => $method)
    {
      // data to insert
      $data = array(
        'class'     => get_class($this),
        'method'    => $method,
        'hook'      => $hook,
        'priority'  => 1,
        'version'   => $this->version,
        'enabled'   => 'y',
        'settings'  => ''
      );

      // insert in database
      $sql[] = $DB->insert_string('exp_extensions', $data);
    }

    // run all sql queries
    foreach ($sql as $query) {
      $DB->query($query);
    }

    return true;
    }
    // END activate_extension
     
     
    // --------------------------------
    //  Update Extension
    // --------------------------------  
    function update_extension($current='')
    {
      global $DB;
        
    if ($current == '' OR $current == $this->version)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
    
    if($current < $this->version) { }

    // init data array
    $data = array();

    // Add version to data array
    $data['version'] = $this->version;    

    // Update records using data array
    $sql = $DB->update_string('exp_extensions', $data, "class = '".get_class($this)."'");
    $DB->query($sql);
  }
  // END update_extension

    // --------------------------------
    //  Disable Extension
    // --------------------------------
    function disable_extension()
    {   
      global $DB;
    
    // Delete records
    $DB->query("DELETE FROM exp_extensions WHERE class = '".get_class($this)."'");
  }
  // END disable_extension

     
}
// END CLASS
```

Answer (score 0):

For EE6 add-on, this "addon.setup.php" file must be created.

So please add this "addon.setup.php" below file in the 'system/user/addons/royal_titles'.

> addon.setup.php

```
<?php
require PATH_THIRD.'royal_titles/config.php';
return array(
    'author'      => '',
    'author_url'  => '',
    'name'        => BW_RT_NAME,
    'description' => BW_RT_DESCRIPTION,
    'version'     => BW_RT_VERSION,
    'namespace'   => 'RT\Addons\RoyalTitles',
    'docs_url'    => BW_RT_DOCUMENTATION,
    'settings_exist' => FALSE
);
```

For ee6, we have changed some code in the 'ext.royal_titles.php' file

> ext.royal_titles.php

```
<?php 
/**
* @package ExpressionEngine
* @author Wouter Vervloet
* @copyright  Copyright (c) 2010, Baseworks
* @license    http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
* 
* This work is licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike 3.0 Unported.
* To view a copy of this license, visit http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/
* or send a letter to Creative Commons, 171 Second Street, Suite 300,
* San Francisco, California, 94105, USA.
* 
*/

require PATH_THIRD.'royal_titles/config.php';

class Royal_titles_ext
{
  public $settings            = array();
  
  public $name                = 'Royal Titles';
  public $version             = 0.6;
  public $description         = "Enable EE global variables for the default weblog title setting.";
  public $settings_exist      = 'n';
  public $docs_url            = '';
  
    // -------------------------------
    // Constructor
    // -------------------------------
    function Royal_titles($settings='')
    {
      $this->__construct($settings);
    }
    
    function __construct($settings='')
    {     
        $this->settings = $settings;    
    }
    // END Super_titles
    
    function parse_preferences($data = array())
    {
      
      global $LOC, $PREFS;
      
      $val = $data['default_entry_title'];
      
      if( ! $val ) return $data;
              
      foreach($data as $key => $var)
        {
            $val = str_replace(LD.$key.RD, $var, $val); 
        }

        if (strpos($val, LD.'current_time') !== FALSE && preg_match_all("/".LD."current_time\s+format=([\"\'])([^\\1]*?)\\1".RD."/", $val, $matches))
        {   
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($matches['0']); $j++)
        {               
            $val = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($matches['0'][$j], '/')."/", $LOC->decode_date($matches['2'][$j], $LOC->now), $val, 1);              
        }
      }

      
      $data['default_entry_title'] = $val;

      return $data;
    }

    // --------------------------------
    //  Activate Extension
    // --------------------------------
    function activate_extension()
    {
      
      global $DB;

    $sql = array();

    // hooks array
    $hooks = array(
      'publish_form_weblog_preferences' => 'parse_preferences'
    );

    // insert hooks and methods
    foreach ($hooks AS $hook => $method)
    {
      // data to insert
      $data = array(
        'class'     => get_class($this),
        'method'    => $method,
        'hook'      => $hook,
        'priority'  => 1,
        'version'   => $this->version,
        'enabled'   => 'y',
        'settings'  => ''
      );

      // insert in database
      $sql[] = ee()->db->insert_string('exp_extensions', $data);
    }

    // run all sql queries
    foreach ($sql as $query) {
      ee()->db->query($query);
    }

    return true;
    }
    // END activate_extension
     
     
    // --------------------------------
    //  Update Extension
    // --------------------------------  
    function update_extension($current='')
    {
      global $DB;
        
    if ($current == '' OR $current == $this->version)
    {
      return FALSE;
    }
    
    if($current < $this->version) { }

    // init data array
    $data = array();

    // Add version to data array
    $data['version'] = $this->version;    

    // Update records using data array
    $sql = ee()->db->update_string('exp_extensions', $data, "class = '".get_class($this)."'");
    ee()->db->query($sql);
  }
  // END update_extension

    // --------------------------------
    //  Disable Extension
    // --------------------------------
    function disable_extension()
    {   
      global $DB;
    
    // Delete records
    ee()->db->query("DELETE FROM exp_extensions WHERE class = '".get_class($this)."'");
  }
  // END disable_extension

     
}
// END CLASS
```

If your addon also have the 'config.php' file at this location "system/user/addons/royal_titles".

> config.php

```
<?php

if ( ! defined('BW_RT_VERSION'))
{
  define('BW_RT_VERSION', '0.6');
  define('BW_RT_NAME', 'Royal Titles');
  define('BW_RT_DESCRIPTION', 'Enable EE global variables for the default weblog title setting.');  
  define('BW_RT_DOCUMENTATION', 'http://support.baseworks.nl/discussions/royal_titles');
  define('BW_RT_DEBUG', FALSE);
}

$config['name'] = BW_RT_NAME;
$config['version'] = BW_RT_VERSION;
$config['description'] = BW_RT_DESCRIPTION;
$config['nsm_addon_updater']['versions_xml'] = '';
```

We have tested this add-on and it is working properly with install and uninstall process on EE6. Please test your functionality of this add-on. If you still get any error then please let us know.
We will recheck this script and solve it.